# Need to understand DFS in GameWalkPuzzle

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have this Python code to build a grid and find the finish point using BFS (amplitud) and DFS (profundidad) algorithms.

T is the starting node and P is the finish node

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# 2022 Modified by: Alejandro Cervantes
# Remember installing pyplot and flask if you want to use WebViewer

# NOTA: WebViewer sólo funcionará si ejecutáis en modo local

from __future__ import print_function

import math
from simpleai.search import SearchProblem, astar, breadth_first, depth_first
from simpleai.search.viewers import BaseViewer,ConsoleViewer,WebViewer


MAP = """
########
#    T #
# #### #
#   P# #
# ##   #
#      #
########  

"""
MAP = [list(x) for x in MAP.split("\n") if x]

COSTS = {
    "up": 1.0,
    "down": 1.0,
    "right": 1.0,
    "left": 1.0,
}


class GameWalkPuzzle(SearchProblem):

    def __init__(self, board):
        self.board = board
        self.goal = (0, 0)
        for y in range(len(self.board)):
            for x in range(len(self.board[y])):
                if self.board[y][x].lower() == "t":
                    self.initial = (x, y)
                elif self.board[y][x].lower() == "p":
                    self.goal = (x, y)

        super(GameWalkPuzzle, self).__init__(initial_state=self.initial)

    def actions(self, state):
        actions = []
        for action in list(COSTS.keys()):
            newx, newy = self.result(state, action)
            if self.board[newy][newx] != "#":
                actions.append(action)
        return actions

    def result(self, state, action):
        x, y = state

        if action.count("up"):
            y -= 1
        if action.count("down"):
            y += 1
        if action.count("left"):
            x -= 1
        if action.count("right"):
            x += 1

        new_state = (x, y)
        return new_state

    def is_goal(self, state):
        return state == self.goal

    def cost(self, state, action, state2):
        return COSTS[action]

    def heuristic(self, state):
        x, y = state
        gx, gy = self.goal
        return math.sqrt((x - gx) ** 2 + (y - gy) ** 2)


def searchInfo (problem,result,use_viewer):
    def getTotalCost (problem,result):
        originState = problem.initial_state
        totalCost = 0
        for action,endingState in result.path():
            if action is not None:
                totalCost += problem.cost(originState,action,endingState)
                originState = endingState
        return totalCost

    
    res = "Total length of solution: {0}\n".format(len(result.path()))
    res += "Total cost of solution: {0}\n".format(getTotalCost(problem,result))
        
    if use_viewer:
        stats = [{'name': stat.replace('_', ' '), 'value': value}
                         for stat, value in list(use_viewer.stats.items())]
        
        for s in stats:
            res+= '{0}: {1}\n'.format(s['name'],s['value'])
    return res


def resultado_experimento(problem,MAP,result,used_viewer):
    path = [x[1] for x in result.path()]

    for y in range(len(MAP)):
        for x in range(len(MAP[y])):
            if (x, y) == problem.initial:
                print("T", end='')
            elif (x, y) == problem.goal:
                print("P", end='')
            elif (x, y) in path:
                print("·", end='')
            else:
                print(MAP[y][x], end='')
        print()

    info=searchInfo(problem,result,used_viewer)
    print(info)

def main():
    problem = GameWalkPuzzle(MAP)
    used_viewer=BaseViewer() 
    # Probad también ConsoleViewer para depurar
    # No podréis usar aquí WebViewer en Collab para ver los árboles
    
    # Mostramos tres experimentos
    print('Amplitud')
    result = breadth_first(problem, graph_search=True,viewer=used_viewer)
    resultado_experimento(problem,MAP,result,used_viewer)
    
    print('Profundidad')
    problem = GameWalkPuzzle(MAP)
    used_viewer=BaseViewer() 
    result = depth_first(problem, graph_search=True,viewer=used_viewer)
    resultado_experimento(problem,MAP,result,used_viewer)

    print('A*')
    problem = GameWalkPuzzle(MAP)
    used_viewer=BaseViewer() 
    result = astar(problem, graph_search=True,viewer=used_viewer)
    resultado_experimento(problem,MAP,result,used_viewer)
```

The thing is, with that start and finish, and the result actions are up, left, down and right (In that order I think), how come the resulting map and path for DFS is:

```
Profundidad
########
#····T #
#·#### #
#···P# #
# ##   #
#      #
########  
Total length of solution: 10
Total cost of solution: 9.0
max fringe size: 3
visited nodes: 10
iterations: 10
```

When it gets to the left wall, shouldn't it keep going down until it hits the bottom and then try right? However, the map shows it turns right in the same level P is and that the nodes the path traverses are the only nodes the algorithm visits.

I'm confused

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the previous question you asked, you haven't marked an answer as accepted. Was it not good enough?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: theoretically `dict` doesn't have to keep element in the same order so it doesn't have to move in expected order - but we can't see your code, and we can't read in your mind - so we have no idea how it work. You should show all details in question (not in comments) as text (not image). And sometimes it is good to show `minimal working code` so we could simply copy and test it.